# Insert big data from csv to mysql gives HTTP ERROR 500 using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

I m trying to insert 400k records from csv to mysql using laravel query builder but it gives http error 500 after inserting almost 150k records on server but on localhost it works fine as expected

i already increase max_execution_time to 99999999..
used try catch but shows nothing

```
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    fgetcsv($handle);
    try {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num  = count($data);
            $row++;

                $insert = [
                'col1' => $data[0],
                'col2' => $data[1],
                'col3' => $data[2],
                'col4' => $data[3],
            ];
            $insertData = DB::table('mytable')->insert($insert);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } catch(\PDOException $e) { 
        if($e->getCode() != 23000){ 
                throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of uploading all 4 Lac records in a one go, why don't you divide CSV in 4 files and upload it?

Comment: You're performing a CSV import via browser/web? Can you use international measurement units?

Comment: Please don't use local measurements. There's perfectly good universal ones that everyone understands

Answer (score -1):

It's really slow to make query to database for each insert. It's much better to make a single insert request for all rows.
Move this line outside of the while loop

```
$insertData = DB::table('mytable')->insert($insert);
```

And change the way how you are collecting data

from

```
$insert = [...];
```

to this

```
$insert[] = [...];
```

Comment: Your solution would hit MySQL's limitation set by `max_packet_size` variable. For this very purpose we use prepared statements and transactions, then we commit every 1000 records in one go - avoiding `max_packet_size` limitation or forcing MySQL to parse entire 500+MB of data. Terrible answer, downvoted because you'd exceed PHP's memory limit, MySQL's `max_packet_size` and you'd incur heavy penalty because batch-query with so much data takes a lot of time to parse.